# AngularJS - input text element deselect event

Tags: angularjs, events

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text1">
    <input type="text" id="text2">
</form>
```

In AngularJS, is there any way for me to determine when, say, the user deselects #text1, for example by clicking #text2, or clicking somewhere else on the screen? I am aware the ng-change lets me listen to changes in the value of #text1 itself, but I see no way to determine when the user actually leaves the field.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ngBlur for this

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text1" ng-blur="iHaveLostFocusDoSomethingWithIt()">
  <input type="text" id="text2">
</form>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that ng-blur is available only since Angular 1.2

Comment: Correct, i keep forgetting that some people use old version for no reason at all ;)